# How to save data locally in hybrid app with cordova?

Tags: cordova, extjs, indexeddb, pouchdb

I need some suggestions to build an hybrid application with cordova for android and iOS, (it will be developed with sencha extjs). It aims to save survey data locally and later when there is a Wi-Fi network load that data (Synchronize) in a remote database manager (MySQL). I have read a bit of indexedDB, webSQL and some tools like pouchDB, but I don't have experience in this branch and I don't know what is better.

What would you recommend?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount of data you'll be expecting to store. If it is in range of KBs then "localStorage" provided by browser should be sufficient. If you end converting between json to and fro to store and retrieve from DB.Then you should be using NoSQL database such as MongoDB to store data.But db option is in server end. To save data only in client side you have all you have is :

> 1. Local Storage
> 2. Session Storage
> 3. Indexed DB
> 4. Web SQL
> 5. Cookies

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have understood to store data on the client side when there is no internet with those tools that you mentioned, what I have'nt understood very well is how to synchronize that data on a remote database server, with MongoDB, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage is the best way for save data locally

Save data to Local storage : localStorage.setItem('item', "1");

Get data from Local storage : localStorage.getItem('item');